# How can I store data from Excel to Hash of arrays?

Tags: perl

I want to read data from excel file and store it to Hash of arrays.

For example, I have an Excel file as below:

[image: Example Excel spreadsheet]

I want to fetch value from datasheet and store it like this:

```
%hash = (
    "A1" => [ "B1", "C1", "D1" ],
    "A2" => [ "B2", "C2", "D2" ],
    "A3" => [ "B3", "C3", "D3" ]
);
```

I have installed [`Spreadsheet::Read`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Read) and used the method  below to store it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl   
use Spreadsheet::Read;
my $workbook = ReadData ("test.xls");
my %hash = (
             "$workbook->[1]{A2}" => ["$workbook->[1]{B2}","$workbook->[1]{B3}"]
           );
    
 print $hash{"$workbook->[1]{A2}"}->[1];
```

But it is not smart.How can I archive it more efficient?

Can anybody give me some suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying that the code you have written works but it is too slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're asking for is a more general program that will process a spreadsheet that contains any number of rows and columns

I've written this according to the [documentation for `Spreadsheet::Read`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Read), which says that it exports a `row` function which will return an array of the elements in the given row number of the given spreadsheet

I've not been able to test this as I don't have a copy of Excel installed, but it does compile successfully and it's fairly simple so I don't anticipate any problems

```
#!/usr/bin/perl   

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Spreadsheet::Read qw/ ReadData row /;

my $workbook = ReadData('test.xls', rc => 1, cells => 0);
my $sheet = $workbook->[1];

my %data;

for my $i ( 1 .. $sheet->{maxrow} ) {
    my ($col1, @rest) = row($sheet, $i);
    $data{ $col1 } = \@rest;
}

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \%data;
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is very straight forward.First count total no of rows and columns in the excel sheet.Then insert the values in the hash

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl   
    use Spreadsheet::Read;
    my $worksheet = ReadData ("test.xls");
    my $workbook = $worksheet->[1];     #excel sheet no

    #row count....
    my $max_rows = $workbook->{'maxrow'};
    #column count...
    my $max_cols = $workbook->{'maxcol'};

    my %hash ;
    for my $row_num (1..($max_rows))
    {
        if(exists $workbook->{'cell'}[1][$row_num])
        {
              #insert values in the hash 
              my $id = $workbook->{'cell'}[1][$row_num];
              my $val1 = $workbook->{'cell'}[2][$row_num];
              my $val2 = $workbook->{'cell'}[3][$row_num];
              my $val3 = $workbook->{'cell'}[4][$row_num];
              push (@{$hash{$id}},$val1, $val2, $val3);
        }
   }
   #hash Reading
   foreach my $id (keys %hash)
   {
       my @arr = @{$hash{$id}};
       print "$id\t@arr\n";
   }
```

You can modify the hash insertion process depending on your requirement